# Mysql dump and restore securely

Tags: mysql

I want to do mysqldump to get backup of all my data bases. suppose if any crash occur in my mysql database, then i will restore that backup file. when try to restore the old backup. after doing backup still the newly created tables are present in the database. is there any option to restore only the old data, and erase all other newly added stuff?

i did following

```
$ mysqldump -u root -proot  --all-databases > alldb_backup.sql
```

restore

```
$ mysqldump -u root -proot < alldb_backup.sql
```

Comment: you can try to use workbech directly  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381577/mysql-workbench-how-to-export-mysql-database-to-sql-file/22382468#22382468

Comment: i have to write a script for that, i can't use tools here.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to delete the entire database and only restore from your backup or do you want to preserve some existing data in your database and restore old data on top of it?

Comment: i want to delete the entire database and only restore from your backup 
@DHS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `--add-drop-database` option. This will delete an existing database so you will start on an empty database when importing the backup.

Make a MySQL backup of all databases:

```
mysqldump --user=root --add-drop-database --complete-insert --extended-insert \
          --verbose --all-databases > alldb_backup.sql
```

Only make a backup of a single database (easier to handle individually):

```
mysqldump --user=root --add-drop-database --complete-insert \
          --extended-insert --verbose mysingledb > mysingledb.sql
```

To restore all databases it is then:

```
mysql --user=root -p < alldb_backup.sql
```

Or to restore a single database:

```
mysql --user=root -p mysingledb < mysingledb.sql
```

Comment: why add-drop option ?

Comment: It will then delete the existing database so you can start from scratch with your new import/backup

Comment: when i did restore the old one, its showing fallowing error. i can guess its because of permission to database. is it ?                 ERROR 1010 (HY000) at line 22: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './PhD', errno: 39)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403565/my-sql-error-code-1010-error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-errno-13

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, but maybe not the best solution is to drop all your databases
except  mysql, information_schema,test and OLD db’s

mysql -uroot -p  -e "show databases" | grep -v Database | grep -v mysql| grep -v information_schema| grep -v test | grep -v OLD |gawk '{print "drop database " $1 ";select sleep(0.1);"}' | mysql -uroot -ppassword

And then restore your backup

$ mysqldump -u root -proot < alldb_backup.sql