# Remove Postgres database from GCP with active connections via GitHub actions

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

When a developer opens a PR for our backend, a new copy from the staging database is created for the PR via a GitHub action.

The database copy is created in the same SQL instance as the staging database, all Postgres in Google Cloud Platform.

When a PR is closed, we run another GitHub action to clean up the resources.

The executed command is

```bash
gcloud sql databases delete ${{ env.TF_VAR_db_name }} -i OurInstance
```

### Problem

The database is not disposed.

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.databases.delete)
HTTPError 400: Invalid request: failed to delete database "db-pr-202".
Detail: pq: database "db-pr-202" is being accessed by other users.
(Please use psql client to delete database that is not owned by "cloudsqlsuperuser").
```

### Question

> How to solve this problem? (*without restarting the instance*)

### What I have tried

#### Terminate connection

I tried terminate the connections in various ways but it either does nothing, or I fail on connection to he instance back because of missing `psql`. Other thing is that there is no one who is actually using the databases.

```yaml
- name: Terminate DB Connections
  run: |
    echo "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '${{ env.TF_VAR_db_name }}' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();" | gcloud sql connect api-db --user=postgres --quiet
```

#### Restart the instance

It works but it can effect the staging environment, so I would like to find some other solution.

Comment: Double-check that there are no connections that have not been closed. Something has an open connection to the database.

Comment: Maybe [DROP DATABASE db_name WITH (FORCE);](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021507/5070879). If it fails then there may be some replication/subscription involved

Comment: check this....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813186/unknown-internal-error-trying-to-remove-google-cloud-sql-postgres-database

Comment: @LukaszSzozda And how can I execute that in GCP via GitHub action? ‍♀️

Comment: @smoore4 as you can see in my question, I already did. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your GitHub Actions workflow to include a step that attempts to forcefully delete the PostgreSQL database. Here's an example

```
name: Delete PostgreSQL Database

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  delete-database:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Set up Google Cloud CLI
  uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
  with:
    project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
    service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
    export_default_credentials: true

- name: Forcefully Delete PostgreSQL Database
  run: |
    # Replace 'your_database_name' and 'OurInstance' with your actual database name and instance name.
    DATABASE_NAME="your_database_name"
    INSTANCE_NAME="OurInstance"
    
    # Forcefully disconnect active connections
    gcloud sql users set-password postgres@${INSTANCE_NAME} --password=random-password
    
    # Retry database deletion
    retries=3
    while [ $retries -gt 0 ]; do
      if gcloud sql databases delete ${DATABASE_NAME} -i ${INSTANCE_NAME}; then
        echo "Database deletion successful."
        break
      else
        echo "Retrying database deletion..."
        sleep 10
        retries=$((retries - 1))
      fi
    done
```

Forcefully Delete PostgreSQL Database:

Sets a random password for the 'postgres' user, which may force active connections to disconnect.
Retries the database deletion, allowing some time for active connections to close.